# Implement a class derived from an interface which derived from another interface

Tags: c++, com

I have the following interfaces and classes

```
public interface IBase
{
    virtual void SomeBaseMethod()=0;
}

public interface IDerived : IBase
{
    virtual void SomeOtherMethod()=0;
}

public class base: public IBase
{
    void SomeBaseMethod(){};
}

public class derived: public base, public IDerived 
{
    void SomeBaseMethod(){};
    void SomeOtherMethod(){};
}
```

In class derived, I have to repeat 'void SomeBaseMethod(){};', which have already implement in my class base. Otherwise I will get compile error. Is it possible not repeat 'void SomeBaseMethod(){};' in my class derived?

Comment: You have a [diamond inheritance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2659116/how-does-virtual-inheritance-solve-the-diamond-multiple-inheritance-ambiguit) problem.

Comment: Which version of C++ has the keyword `interface`.  Looks more like Java.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews It is not standard C++, but it is an [extension in Visual Studio](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/737cydt1.aspx) (which I discourage using)

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, you have to repeat yourself here. C++ has virtual inheritance, which would solve this problem, but you can't use virtual inheritance with COM interfaces. [Here's an explanation as to why](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3081871/why-cant-we-use-virtual-inheritance-in-com).